# Drive Batch API returning text content in addition to json-parsable stuff

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

My batch process (the creation of some folders) goes just fine, but the response i'm getting back isn't the clean JSON I was expecting but it has plain text headers interspersed. How do I get rid of them or parse this correctly?

```
--batch__AAPXnCR1-5Q
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 22:44:16 GMT
Expires: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 22:44:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 140

{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1pznPt",
 "name": "SF1-B1",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}

--batch_z3tbQ5Q
```

I just need to be able to extract the id nd nams of these folders after they are created.

Comment: Thats the response you get its your job to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

Unfortunately, the response value cannot be directly parsed using the built-in function of Google Apps Script and Javascript. So in my case, I parse the response value using the following script. I think that there are several methods for this situation. So please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script 1:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText(); // Here, the batch request is run.

var temp = response.split("--batch");
var parsedValue = temp.slice(1, temp.length - 1).map(function(e){return JSON.parse(e.match(/{[\S\s]+}/g)[0])});
```

#### Sample script 2:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText(); // Here, the batch request is run.

var parsedValue = response.match(/{[\s\S]+?}/g).map(function(e) {return JSON.parse(e)});
```

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this. BTW, the base code i'm using came from your github, very helpful!

Comment: @J. G. Thank you for replying and using it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.